# A doubt regarding sampling with and without replacement

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-distribution, sampling

For a positive integer $N$, let $[N] = \{1,\cdots,N\}$ and $\binom{[N]}{n}$ denotes the set of all $n$ sized subsets of $[N]$. Supose we want to pick $(n+1)$-sized sample of $[N]$ uniformly randomly (meaning every element of $\binom{[N]}{n+1}$ is sampled with equal probability). This can be clearly done by picking $n+1$ elements without replacement. This is equivalent to the follwing 2-staged random process

1. > Sample an element of $\binom{[N]}{n}$ uniformly. Call this sample $X$.
2. > Sample an element $i$ from $[N]\setminus X$

Then it can be shown that $Y=X\cup\{i\}$ is a uniform element of $\binom{[N]}{n+1}$, i.e. for a fixed $I\in \binom{[N]}{n+1}, Pr[Y=I] = \frac{1}{\binom{N}{n+1}}$.

**Proof:** Fix $I=\{i_1,\cdots, i_{n+1}\}$. Then $Pr[Y=I] = \sum_{j=1}^{n+1}Pr[i=i_j\mid X=I\setminus\{i_j\}]Pr[X=I\setminus\{i_j\}] = \frac{n+1}{N-n}\cdot \frac{1}{\binom{N}{n}} = \frac{1}{\binom{N}{n+1}}$

Similary If we sample $Y$ from $\binom{[N]}{n+1}$ and delete a uniform random element $i$ from $Y$, then $X=Y\setminus \{i\}$ is a uniform random element of $\binom{[N]}{n}$.

**Proof:** Fix $I\in \binom{[N]}{n}$. Then $Pr[X=I] = \sum_{j\in [N]\setminus I}Pr[i=j\mid Y = I\cup\{j\}]Pr[Y = I\cup\{j\}] = \frac{N-n}{n+1}\cdot \frac{1}{\binom{N}{n+1}} = \frac{1}{\binom{N}{n}}$

Now let $[N]^n$ denotes the set of all ordered $n$-tuples of $[N]$. In order to sample a uniform element of $[N]^{n+1}$, we first sample an uniform element $X$ of $[N]^n$ and then sample an uniform $i$ from $[N]$. Then $Y=(X,i)$ is a uniform element of $[N]^{n+1}$.

**Proof:** Fix $I=(I^-,i_{n+1})\in [N]^{n+1}$, where $I^-\in [N]^n$. Then $Pr[Y=I] = Pr[\{X=I^-\} \cap\{i=i_{n+1}\}] = Pr[i=i_{n+1}\mid X=I^-]Pr[X=I^-] = \frac{1}{N}\cdot \frac{1}{N^n} = \frac{1}{N^{n+1}}$.

Now my question: In order to generate a uniform sample from $[N]^n$, we generate a uniform $Y$ from $[N]^{n+1}$ and just discard the last entry. My proposed proof is following:

**Proof:** Fix $I \in [N]^n$. Then if $X=(Y,i)$, $Pr[Y=I]. = \sum_{j=1}^N Pr[Y=I\mid X=(I,j)]Pr[X=(I,j)]$. Now the term $Pr[Y=I\mid X=(I,j)] = 1$, because $I$ is already fixed. So the above expression is equal to $\frac{1}{N^n}$.

Is the last proof correct? My initial thought was that removing a random element from $Y$ would give the result, but I could not prove it. I think the first three proofs are correct. Correct me I am wrong.

The motivaion for this question is analysis of some random process, see for example Lemma 6 of [Algorithms for lp Low-Rank Approximation](https://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-dpwoodru/cgklpw17.pdf). Without going into much detail, there is was shown a random element of $\binom{[N]}{2k}$ has some property. The way it was shown that first sampling an element of $\binom{[N]}{2k+1}$ and then removing a random elemet from the sample. I have seen such argument elsewhere also.

Comment: Your fourth proof is completely correct. I have some unsolicited stylistic advice. It makes things more clear if you always use capital letters for random things, and lowercase letters for deterministic realizations, like $P(X\le x)$ for the cdf. So I would write your proof as: "Fix $\vec y\in [N]^n$. Then $P(Y=\vec y)=\sum_j P(Y=\vec y|X=(\vec y,j))=\dots$"

Comment: @MikeEarnest thanks and duly noted. So suppose I sample  $n+1$ elements from $[N]$ uniformly and independently with replacement and then remove a uniformly sampled element from the sample, this does not give a uniform random sample of size $n$, as is the case with sampling without replacement?

Comment: It should be uniform even if you delete a random entry from $X\in [N]^{n+1}$, instead of the last entry. This is because deleting any fixed entry leaves a uniform element of $[N]^{n+1}$ (your same proof works; just let $Y$ be the result of deleting that entry), so by the law of total probability, deleting a random entry is also uniform. If this is unclear, I will write up an answer when I have time.